# Jenkins Pipeline Git Push

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there as way to have a stage like so in a Jenkinsfile:

```
stage('Create Branch & Push Branch') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh "git checkout -b release/${NEW_TAG}"
                    sh "git push --set-upstream
                }
            }
    }
```

Currently this leads to:

> - git push --set-upstream origin release/v1.0.3
>     fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such device or address
>     script returned exit code 128

The repository was originally cloned earlier in the pipeline using:

```
checkout poll: false, scm: [$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: 'develop']], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 'CleanBeforeCheckout'], [$class: 'CleanCheckout'], [$class: 'CloneOption', depth: 0, noTags: false, reference: '', shallow: false]], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'ci-github', url: 'https://github.com/my-org/my-repo.git']]]
```

That part works ok (the clone), presumably because I can supply this step with the jenkins credential id for github.

Is there a way for me to do the same to push back to a repo that was cloned earlier in the build?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I've made this work using:

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'ci-github', passwordVariable: 'GIT_PASSWORD', usernameVariable: 'GIT_USERNAME')]) {
                        sh('git push https://${GIT_USERNAME}:${GIT_PASSWORD}@github.com/my-org/my-repo.git')
                    }
```

After reading https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-examples/blob/master/pipeline-examples/push-git-repo/pushGitRepo.groovy and https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28335.

An alternative approach using SSH keys appears to be :

```
sshagent(['credentiald-id-using-ssh-key']) 
 {
    sh('git command or program calling git inside') 
 }
```

Comment: **fatal: You are not currently on a branch.**
To push the history leading to the current (detached HEAD) state now, use
`git push https://****:****@repository.git HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>`

Answer (score 1):

To get this working for blue ocean (which uses https connection) use the following:

```
sshagent(credentials: ["406ef572-9598-45ee-8d39-9c9a227a9227"]) {
                    def repository = "git@" + env.GIT_URL.replaceFirst(".+://", "").replaceFirst("/", ":")
                    sh("git remote set-url origin $repository")
                    sh("git tag --force build-${env.BRANCH_NAME}")
                    sh("git push --force origin build-${env.BRANCH_NAME}")
                }
```

Comment: Not sure what exactly should be different for you, but my original example above was used on blue ocean and works fine (at least for me).

Answer (score 1):

Github no longer supports password authentication. Instead use a personal access token. Please refer: [How to use Github Personal Access Token in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61105368/how-to-use-github-personal-access-token-in-jenkins)