# How to use Github Personal Access Token in Jenkins

Tags: authentication, jenkins, github, jenkins-github-plugin

I can ask this question in many ways, like
How to configure Jenkins credentials with Github Personal Access Token
How to clone Github repo in Jenkins using Github Personal Access Token

So this is the problem

---

The alternate solution that I am aware of

- `SSH` connection
- `username` `password` configuration in Jenkins. However,
  [use of a password with the GitHub API is now deprecated](https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-14-deprecating-password-auth/).

But My question is how to setup Github connection with Jenkins using `Personal Access Token`

Answer (score 101, accepted):

[UPDATE]
The new solution proposed by git is

https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/

Which says:

> Beginning August 13, 2021, we will no longer accept account passwords
> when authenticating Git operations and will require the use of
> token-based authentication, such as a personal access token (for
> developers) or an OAuth or GitHub App installation token (for
> integrators) for all authenticated Git operations on GitHub.com. You
> may also continue using SSH keys where you prefer.

What you need to do:

https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/#what-you-need-to-do-today

Basically, change the add URL as

`https://<access token>@github.com/<userName>/<repository>.git`

Something like this

`https://<access token>@github.com/dupinder/NgnixDockerizedDevEnv.git`

and set the credentials to none.

Thanks to @Gil Stal

---

[OLD Technique]

After many discussion on multiple threads from Stackoverflow

I found one thread that is useful.

Refer to this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61104603/5108695

---

Basically
`Personal access token` can be used as a password, as far as `Jenkins` is concerned at least. I added new credentials to the credential manager.

Go to `Jenkins`

- Go to `credentials` > `System` > `Global credentials` > `Add credentials` a page will open.
- In **Kind** drop-down select **Username and password**.
- In User put a non-existing username like `jenkins-user` or `user`.
- Add `Personal Access Token` in the password field

---

Now start configuring your project.

- **source code management** tab, select new configured credentials from Drop-down near **credential** Under **Repository URL**

So this is how we can configure or setup Authentication between Jenkins and Github using Personal Access Token

References: 
[Git Clone in Jenkins with Personal Access Token idles forever](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56809684/5108695)
[Change jenkins pipeline to use github instead of gitlab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60971714/5108695)

Comment: Be careful not to copy the space at the end of the Personal Access Token.

Comment: In GitHub, it's important to set the Personal Access Token's permissions correctly. e.g. you may need to turn on "repo" permissions for your token in GitHub

Comment: I found this as The Easiest way to use Personal Access Token in Jenkins CI/CD Jobs.

Comment: It looks like this is not working anymore

Comment: There are two problems with this approach: 1) the PAT is now written into your logs any time the URL is written, and 2) the PAT has to be copied into the URL of every job that needs it. These undesirable side-effects make this answer undesirable.

Comment: You may also need to set the Personal Access Token's permissions on the organization as well as the repository.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer wont work anymore because of this: https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations.

You will need to:

1. Change the URL of the repo to: `https://<access token>@github.com/<user-name>/<repo-name>.git` (Replace every `<...>` with the real parameters)
2. Set the credentials to none.

Comment: I am getting repository not found.

Comment: You should change the repo url according to your own details. Iv'e updated the answer for clarity.

Comment: "The accepted answer" can change. Which answer?

Answer (score 3):

Whilst adding the access token to the URL (as per the accepted answer) works, it does not seem particularly good practice, since it means your **secret** access token is now peppered throughout your Jenkins logs.

Instead, you can:

- store your personal access token as a credential on Jenkins
- configure your job to use the stored token

---

**1. Store Your GitHub Token on Jenkins**
As a Jenkins user with appropriate permissions:

- Under Manage Jenkins > Manage Credentials, add new credentials to the global domain (or whichever scope is relevant for you):
  [image]
- Configure the following fields:

  - Kind: "Username with password", even though it is a token. Last I tested it would not be available for selection when configuring the Jenkins job if another kind was configured.
  - Enter your GitHub username.
  - Enter the personal access token in the Password field.
  - Can leave the ID blank, or set to something easier to recognise.
  - A description is helpful too.
    [image]
- Press Create.

---

**2. Configure Your Job to Use the Token**

In the configuration for your job, under Source Code Management > Git, set:

- Repository URL: Set to the usual URL for your repo (no token required).
- Credentials: Select the github token created above.
  [image]
- Alternatively if using a declarative Pipeline, can add a step like:

  ```
  git branch: 'main', credentialsId: 'GitHub-token', url: 'https://github.com/your-github-username/your-repo'
  ```

Answer (score 3):

For a Personal access token chose the username and password and add the token for both the username and password section on the new credentials to the credential manager.

Go to Jenkins

```
Go to credentials > System > Global credentials > Add credentials
On the Kind drop-down select Username and password.
On the User section put the token.
Add the token in the password field
Then save
```

Answer (score 2):

As for credentials for `Jenkins Github Plugin`, please be aware only `Personal access tokens` are now accepted by this plugin.

To generate such a token, follow the Github docs (e.g. [here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token)). Don't save it, it can be regenerated in Github and updated in Jenkins if lost or when migrating to a different server.

To add the token do Jenkins credentials store, go to `<JENKINS_URL:PORT>/credentials/store/system/domain/_/newCredentials` and select Kind "Secret text" (not the default "Username and password"), then paste the token as Secret and choose some ID.

Testing: the credential should appear on the list of Credentials at `<JENKINS_URL:PORT>/credentials/` and be selectable from the drop-down list at `<JENKINS_URL:PORT>/configure/`, where pressing the "Test connection" button should display "Credentials verified for user <GITHUB_USER>".

---

More info: see the Github plugin [docs](https://plugins.jenkins.io/github/).

Caveats: Git Plugin has its [long-standing issues](https://github.com/jenkinsci/ghprb-plugin/issues/534), so if the newly created "Secret text" does not appear in your pipelines, try if this solution helps (with "the user who triggered the build" considered safer than "SYSTEM"):
[client-and-managed-masters/why-credentials-are-not-listed-in-the-git-scm-section](https://docs.cloudbees.com/docs/cloudbees-ci-kb/latest/client-and-managed-masters/why-credentials-are-not-listed-in-the-git-scm-section)

Comment: The secret key does not appear on my list, only "Username and password"
2 days ago the plugin stopped working "message":"Bad credentials...."

Answer (score 2):

As of August 2021 the answer posted by Dupinder Singh is accurate. The only thing I would add is that if you are part of a team, the url format appears to be a bit different. This is what worked for me:

```
https://<access token>@github.com/<team>/<repo>.git
```

for example

```
https://ghp_6dh3jdk394jsmbh299jjdg20fh87hd83ksk39@github.com/MyKuleTeam/KuleGuyCode.git
```

Note that if you use a personal access token you don't need to have any github credentials stored in jenkins.

Answer (score 1):

There is (yet another) way to do this as of 2020/04 which is supposed to be superior to personal access tokens. The best part is that you can continue using a username/password-style credential, and the plugin will handle authenticating with GitHub in the background.

Benefits include:

- **Larger rate limits** - The rate limit for a GitHub app scales with your organization size, whereas a user based token has a limit of 5000 regardless of how many repositories you have.
- **User-independent authentication** - Each GitHub app has its own user-independent authentication. No more need for 'bot' users or figuring out who should be the owner of 2FA or OAuth tokens.
- **Improved security and tighter permissions** - GitHub Apps offer much finer-grained permissions compared to a service user and its personal access tokens. This lets the Jenkins GitHub app require a much smaller set of privileges to run properly.
- **Access to GitHub Checks API** - GitHub Apps can access the the GitHub Checks API to create check runs and check suites from Jenkins jobs and provide detailed feedback on commits as well as code annotation

Links:

- https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2020/04/16/github-app-authentication/
- https://github.com/jenkinsci/github-branch-source-plugin/blob/master/docs/github-app.adoc