# Integration of Jenkins with Github that has MFA configured to github account

Tags: github, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, multi-factor-authentication

I need to copy files from Github that has mutlifactor authentication and paste those on a server, for this I need to write a pipeline in Jenkins how can I do the above?

How can I integrate Github with Jenkins where there is MFA in Github with OTP

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to setup Personal Access Tokens in case MFA is in placed.
   For same you can follow official guide [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)
2. For adding Personal Access token in Jenkins please follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61105368/how-to-use-github-personal-access-token-in-jenkins)

Comment: @NIdhi Rao If this answer resolved your problem, then please consider accepting it, by clicking the green checkmark to the left of this answer.